# Letting others off-server use my forms java script or php

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if anyone could offer me some suggestions as to the best method to accomplish the following:

I have a few html forms that simply post a php page for processing of data.

What would be the best method of letting other people implement my form on their website OFF of my server? (important because I tried a simple php include, but doing this off server is an issue.)

I have tried file_get_contents but this method does not respect css.

I am looking for the most simple, elegant solution to provide affiliates with a way to add my form to their website with one line of code.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. Do you just want to provide the form or do you mean you want it to provide a window to your data? Why is providing access to the PHP source code an issue? I don't understand what you mean regarding file_get_contents() affecting CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Give them the HTML/CSS and Javascript to put on their own website or;
2. Create an iframe to your form which they can drop in their website or;
3. Create a javascript file which will build the HTML and include all the relevant CSS/JS files as it needs to. You can then give them some code like this and get them to put it in their website where they want their form.

> <script type="text/javascript"
>   src="http://url.to/your/website/and/the/script.js"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>           runBuildFormFunction();
>   </script>

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it's a huge security issue; It's possible for a hacker to change the content of the location to a bad location.

You can probably do this by setting

```
allow_url_include = 1
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

(And therefor allowing require and include over the internet).

I also read that PEAR HTTP_Request2 module or the curl functions can be used to fetch webpages.

But you should consider NOT doing this, simply allow people to copy/paste the form to their website.